# Transform Shopify JSONL file to JSON

Tags: json, jq, json-ld

I have a Shopify jsonl file that I'm trying to map to a different json structure.

Given this input:

```
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/123456789","title":"Gift Card"}
{"originalSrc":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1111\/2222\/products\/gift-card-01.jpg","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/123456789"}
{"originalSrc":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1111\/2222\/products\/gift-card-02.jpg","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/123456789"}
```

I'd like to have the images, mapped to the correct product id using __parentId.

```
[
  {
    "id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/123456789",
    "title":"Gift Card",
    "images: [
      "https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1111\/2222\/products\/gift-card-01.jpg",
      "https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1111\/2222\/products\/gift-card-02.jpg"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: If anyone has a solution written in Ruby, I would thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution first incrementally constructs both the dictionary and the array of objects with an id,
and then produces the desired result using `map`:

```
reduce inputs as $x ({};
  if $x|has("id") then .objects += [$x]
  elif $x|has("__parentId") then .dict[$x.__parentId] += [$x.originalSrc]
  else . # an error?
  end)
| .dict as $dict
| .objects
| map( . + {images: $dict[.id]})
```

#### Invocation

The -n command-line ooption must be used, e.g.

```
jq -nf shopify.jq shopify.json
```